I have a error in my system using xampp i already did some of the answer i see in stackoverflow
I have inventory system that can generate sales report if the user click the sold button in inventory it will remove in inventory and generate sales report i think my code is right but i got this problem.
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\POS-IMS-CI\application\models\sales_model.php on line 54
Im using codeigniter right now and this my controller for my sold button function
public function sold($id) {
        $this->load->model('sales_model');
        $this->load->model('item_model');
        $this->load->database();

        $item = $this->item_model->getItemById($id);

        if ($item) {
            $sale_data = array(
                'item_id' => $item->id,
                'item_name' => $item->name,
                'storage' => $item->storage,
                'serial' => $item->serial,
                'sub_total' => $item->price,
            );

            $file = fopen('sales_report.csv', 'a');
            fputcsv($file, $sale_data);
            fclose($file);

            $this->db->trans_start();
            $this->sales_model->insert_sales_single($sale_data);

            if ($item->quantity > 1) {
                $this->item_model->decrementQuantity($id);
            } else {
                $this->item_model->deleteItem($id);
            }

            $this->db->trans_complete();

            if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('errorMessage', '<div class="alert alert-danger">Failed to mark item as sold.</div>');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('successMessage', '<div class="alert alert-success">Item sold and added to sales report!</div>');
            }
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('errorMessage', '<div class="alert alert-danger">Item not found.</div>');
        }

        redirect(base_url('inventory'));
    }

And this is my Model for it
public function sold($id) {
        $this->load->model('item_model');
    }
    public function getItemById($id) {
        $this->db->select('id, name, storage, serial, price, quantity');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('items');
        return $query->row();
    }


Please provide a [mre] of the issue. Starting off with the assumption that your code is correct is rarely a good idea. Something is causing php to use more than its allocation of memory during a single execution. That's unusual, and the prime cause is usually something inefficient in the code and/or the data being processed. Please [edit] your question. See also [ask] for more guidance.

This is not a database related error, just a pure php one. Btw, xampp replaced mysql with mariadb years ago, just did not make a good job of telling users...

done edit i add the code for the sold button function please help =(

Are you using a framework and/or ORM? If so please add a relevant tag. Obviously we don't know what goes on any of those model classes or the calls to them, but they look like they probably belong to a known product
